# Bundler can't find win32-service gem even thought it appears in gem list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to use bundler in a `2.3.4` `Rails` app and am having problems with the `win32-service` gem. The gem was installed by issuing `gem install win32-service --platform mswin32`. I installed it outside of bundler as bundler always tries to compile from source which fails miserably.

Output of `gem list`

```
win32-service (0.7.1 x86-mswin32-60)
```

Output of `bundle install`

```
Your Gemfile doesn't have any sources. You can add one with a line like 'source :gemcutter'
Could not find gem 'win32-service (>= 0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources.
```

I tried using source :gemcutter but as noted above bundler tries to use the source package that does not build.

I have also tried using older versions of the gem (`0.5.1`) and had the same problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add **source :rubygems** to the top of your Gemfile.

Comment: That doesn't help me, the gem is already installed so bundler should source it from the system. The gem is also inside vendor/cache.